# Change bottom bar to any color in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How to change the bottom bar to any color in Flutter
[image]

I've tried using

```
AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
  value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.red,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.yellow
  ),
  child: child,
);
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SafeArea above Scaffold and wrap SafeArea with Container then try using color of that container.

```
class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: const Center(
            child: Text('Test Screen'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that some hack? It works for the background. However, it doesn't set the proper text color on the status bar.

Comment: It's not the only solution there may be other ways to do that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).